# Map Caps Lock to Control while keeping the regular Control key on Windows

Tags: windows, keyboard, capslock

There are a lot of resources on how to swap Caps Lock and Control on Windows, but all of them swap
Caps Lock and Control. What I want is to have Caps Lock as Control without mapping Control to Caps
Lock. In other words, I want to have both Caps Lock AND Control mapped to Control.

How can I do that please?

(I don't mind using third party software.)

Answer (score 1):

Load a registry file containing these lines:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Keyboard Layout]
"Scancode Map"=hex:00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,02,00,00,00,1d,00,3a,00,00,00,00,00
```

Comment: Wouldn't that swap the keys instead of setting both to Control?

Comment: No. This would swap them: `Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Keyboard Layout]
"Scancode Map"=hex:00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,03,00,00,00,3a,00,1d,00,1d,00,3a,00,\
  00,00,00,00`

Answer (score 0):

I found this program that does what I want: [SharpKeys](http://sharpkeys.codeplex.com/).